# Freebase: how to query /common/document/text?

Tags: javascript, freebase

Freebase: Hi, good day for evryone. Does anybody know how to access the property **/common/document/text**, that you get on this [freebase link](http://www.freebase.com/m/015fk)?

I query it like this
    [{
      "id": "/m/015fk",
      "type": "/common/document",
      "text": null
    }]

But the results I get is null

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the Text API https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/m/015fk but you'd probably be better off using the Topic API.